# Compress regexp pattern to a shorter regexp for mysql query

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to use the following regex for finding any words that have a and b or a and c and any one of these letters (f or g) i use this regexp and work very well but :
there is a another way that shorter than my used pattern?

my used regexp :

```
(f|g).*a.*(b|c)|a.*(f|g).*(b|c)|a.*(b|c).*(f|g)
```

my tested text :

```
-----------------------------------------------
          txt               |   matches 
-----------------------------------------------
test with g a b             |   YES
test with m n s             |   NO
test with a g b             |   YES
test with a b g             |   YES
test with e r q             |   NO
test with fg a fg b fg      |   YES
-----------------------------------------------
```

i want checking a words should have a and b and f or g. but f or g there are any where of word and one of then for example i an checking like these : abg - abf - gab - fab - agb - afb - gab - fab and not matching with this : gcd - it doesn't have a and b.

Comment: I can only suggest `[fg].*a.*[bc]|a.*[fg].*[bc]|a.*[bc].*[fg]`. MySQL regex is not rich, and since there are no lookarounds there, you won't have any chance making the pattern shorter.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor Stribiżew. That is no way to say that at least one of these letters is a part of the text? Without having to specify the location of the letters. Because I got in this pattern before and after or in the middle of words.

Comment: i want checking a words should have a and b and f or g. but f or g there are any where of word and one of then for example i an checking like these : abg - abf - gab - fab - agb - afb - gab - fab and not matching with this : gcd - gay beacuse doesn't have a and b.

Answer (score 0):

If this type of query is the main one, then I would suggest `a.*[bc].*[fg]` *after* sorting the letters.

Probably you want to sort the letters into a new column so as not to mangle the original string.

Comment: i want checking a words should have a and b and f or g. but f or g there are any where of word and one of then for example i an checking like these : abg - abf - gab - fab - agb - afb - gab - fab and not matching with this : gcd - gay beacuse doesn't have a and b.

Comment: Hence sorting the letters.